# Двумерные массивы.Сумма элементов j-строки не превышала 3

Tags: c++, массивы

В меню ресторана M блюд. В течение дня ресторан обслужил N посетителей. При этом посетители заказывали только по три блюда. Определить наиболее и наименее популярные блюда.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int i, j, s;
    const int m = 5, n = 5;
    int mass[m][n];
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                mass[i][j] = rand() % 2;
            }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << mass[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            s = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                s += mass[i][j];
            }
            cout << s << '\n';
        }
return(0);
```

Я сделал двумерный массив и сумму элементов в нем по строкам. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать это: "При этом посетители заказывали только по три блюда", у меня идея - сделать так, чтобы сумма элементов  j-строки не превышала 3. И как вычленить из суммы всех строк максимальный и минимальный?

Answer (score 1):

Одномерный массив блюд длиной `M`.

Двумерный массив заказов `3 x N`. Значения элементов - индексы из первого массива. Наверное, с ограничением - в одном заказе не может повторяться одно и то же блюдо?

Одномерный массив счетчиков заказанных блюд длиной `M`.

Заполнить массив счетчиков, исходя из данных заказов. Найти в массиве счетчиков минимум и максимум.

Comment: Да, не может одно и тоже блюдо повторяться.

Comment: Да,  и чтобы у одного клиента было только 3 блюда

Comment: @darcinc Двумерный массив заказов **3** x N.

Comment: вы предлагаете, чтобы у клиентов был выбор только из 3 блюд?

Comment: @darcinc Нет, Вы невнимательно прочитали ответ.